# Example where Čech and derived functor cohomologies don't agree.

Tags: examples-counterexamples, homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, derived-functors

I'm studying sheaf cohomology, and I've seen that Čech and derived functor cohomologies agree, at least on paracompact Hausdorff topological spaces.

Is there a simple example of a topological space $X$ with a sheaf $\mathcal F$ such that these two cohomologies don't agree? (I don't have any knowledge of schemes, I want $X$ to be a topological space)

Comment: A scheme is in particular a topological space, and their sheaf cohomology only depends on the topology. In fact, they are very simple as topological spaces. :p

Comment: More seriously, one can prove without any hypotheses at all that Čech cohomology (after taking the direct limit over all open covers) always computes the correct $H^1$, so any counterexample has to be in $H^2$ or higher.

Comment: So, is there such an example for $H^2$?

Comment: Answered on [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/122478/an-example-where-ech-and-derived-functor-cohomologies-dont-agree-closed).

Answer (score 2):

So as to answer this question, I will give a link to a paper:

> http://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.2524v1.pdf.
>
> **Abstract:** "*We construct a non-paracompact Hausdorff space for which Cech cohomology does not coincide with sheaf cohomology. Moreover, the sheaf of continuous real-valued functions is neither soft nor acyclic, and our space admits non-numerable principal bundles.*"

The construction is quite long, and so I'll refer you to that paper.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/122478/an-example-where-ech-and-derived-functor-cohomologies-dont-agree 

You're an active MO user. Didn't you see this was already answered there, with the same reference?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Forgive me; didn't see that. I made the answer CW. Again, I apologize for not seeing the answer at MO.